# vuepress local search not showing up [version 2.0.0-beta.22]

Tags: vuepress

I am new to vueppress.

I followed the docs [here](https://v2.vuepress.vuejs.org/) to create a documentation site. things went well but the search field/input didn't show up. I tried to follow the plugin installation docs [here](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/plugin/official/plugin-search.html#install) but I got:

1. I need to install `@vuepress/shared-utils`
2. after that I had to install `@vue/component-compiler-utils` too

but was unable to see the search input. I also tried to add the following to my `./docs/.vuepress/config.ts` but still no luck.

```
plugins: [
    [
      '@vuepress/plugin-search',
      {
        searchMaxSuggestions: 10
      }
    ],
  ]
```

I don't want to use Algoia search as this is internal documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Everything was working except the **search box** was *not* visible.

The issue was that my `...docs/.vuepress/config.ts` was not structured properly. To fix it I followed exactly what the VuePress documentation instructed.

**The working config.ts structure**

```ts
import { defaultTheme } from '@vuepress/theme-default'
import { searchPlugin } from '@vuepress/plugin-search'

module.exports = {
  theme: defaultTheme({
    ...
  }),

  plugins: [
    searchPlugin({
      ...
    })
  ]
}
```

Currently I am using **VuePress** `v2.0.0-beta.45`
and I used the following to install what I needed:

```
npm i -D @vuepress/plugin-search@next
npm i -D @vuepress/plugin-register-components@next
```

**Detailed `config.ts` that is working for me**

```ts
import { path } from '@vuepress/utils'
import { defaultTheme } from '@vuepress/theme-default'

// Plugins
import { searchPlugin } from '@vuepress/plugin-search'
import { registerComponentsPlugin } from '@vuepress/plugin-register-components'

import navBarItems from './public/navbar'
import sideBar from './public/sidebar'

// SEE: https://v2.vuepress.vuejs.org/reference/default-theme/config.html#config
module.exports = {
  // Site Config: https://v2.vuepress.vuejs.org/reference/config.html#site-config
  lang: 'en-US',
  title: 'Title on Tab and Navbar',
  description: '',

  // https://v2.vuepress.vuejs.org/reference/default-theme/config.html
  theme: defaultTheme({
    logo: 'logo-light.png',
    logoDark: 'logo-dark.png',

    //https://v2.vuepress.vuejs.org/reference/default-theme/config.html#navbar
    navbar: navBarItems,
    
    // https://v2.vuepress.vuejs.org/reference/default-theme/config.html#sidebar
    sidebar: sideBar  
  }),

  plugins: [
    // https://v2.vuepress.vuejs.org/reference/plugin/register-components.html
    registerComponentsPlugin({
      componentsDir: path.resolve(__dirname, './components')
    }),

    // https://v2.vuepress.vuejs.org/reference/plugin/search.html#search
    searchPlugin({
      // getExtraFields: (page) => page.frontmatter.tags,
      maxSuggestions: 15,
      hotKeys: ['s', '/'],
      locales: {
        '/': {
          placeholder: 'Search',
        }
      }
    })
  ],
}
```

Note that I keep my `sidebar` array and `navbar` object in different files.
Also I couldn't find any **TypeScript** reference for the config in **VuePress 2x**